# Rust Strings with Racer Code Completion

Tags: rust, code-completion

If I declare a string literal as:

```
let text = "this is text";
text.  // Racer returns no completion options
```

Racer doesn't return any completion options after type `text.`

However, if I declare a string literal as:

```
let text: String = "this is text";
text.  // Racer returns many completion options
```

Racer will return completion options after typing `text.`

I don't suspect any problem with Racer, but rather my understanding of Rust strings.  Can someone explain to me why Racer doesn't return any completion options for the first example, and how I might be able to see what methods are available to `text`?

Comment: *I don't suspect any problem with Racer* => Racer is a godsend, but it's still rather limited in its understanding of the type system AFAIK (there's work in progress on the Rust Language Server which will be a Racer on steroids). From my own understanding of strings, I'd suspect you hit a limitation here.

Comment: Relevant Racer issue: https://github.com/phildawes/racer/issues/443 - it's in the works!

Comment: btw, `text` in your example is a `&'static str`, not a `String` (so I'm not sure that Racer suggestions aside, your code would compile). In the general case, due to type inference, adding type hints would probably help Racer anyway to search methods on the right type